# Multiplying matrices that are stored in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

This may seem like a silly question, but I am a bloody newby in Python (and in programming). I am running a physics simulation that involves many (~10 000) 2x2 matrices that I store in an array. I call these matrices M and the array T in the code below. Then I simply want to compute the product of all of these matrices. This is what I came up with, but it looks ugly and it would be so much work for 10000+ 2x2 matrices. Is there a simpler way or an inbuilt function that I could use?

```
import numpy as np
#build matrix M (dont read it, just an example, doesnt matter here)    
def M(k1 , k2 , x):
    a = (k1 + k2) * np.exp(1j * (k2-k1) * x)
    b = (k1 - k2) * np.exp(-1j * (k1 + k2) * x)
    c = (k1 - k2) * np.exp(1j * (k2 + k1) * x)
    d = (k1 + k2) * np.exp(-1j * (k2 - k1) * x)
    M = np.array([[a , b] , [c , d]])
    M *= 1. / (2. * k1)
    return M


#array of test matrices T
T = np.array([M(1,2,3), M(3,3,3), M(54,3,9), M(33,11,42) ,M(12,9,5)])
#compute the matrix product of T[0] * T[1] *... * T[4]
#I originally had this line of code, which is wrong, as pointed out in the comments
#np.dot(T[0],np.dot(T[1], np.dot(T[2], np.dot(T[2],np.dot(T[3],T[4])))))
#it should be:
np.dot(T[0], np.dot(T[1], np.dot(T[2],np.dot(T[3],T[4]))))
```

Comment: Are the matrices always `i * M` for `i` from 1 upto some number?

Comment: no, they are really complicated. I actually plan to compute them on the fly in a for loop, if I can figure out how to do it. should I change that in my code snippet? maybe it's confusing.

Comment: Is there a reason for putting the matrices in an array?  I think I would probably just put them in a list ...

Comment: Indeed, a list would probably even be faster with a `for` loop.

Comment: ok, now I'm done editing. the reason why I put them into an array is because I do numerical calculations. I don't know how it would affect the precision if I put it into a list. does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very NumPythonic, but you could do:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: np.dot(x,y), T, np.eye(2))
```

Or more concisely, as suggested

```
reduce(np.dot, T, np.eye(2))
```

Comment: `lambda x, y: np.dot(x, y)` is just `np.dot`.

Comment: I was thinking that this seemed like a job for `reduce`

Comment: you dont need the identity matrix, `reduce(np.dot, T)` works fine

Comment: are you sure that this is valid? maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I'm getting different results. with my method above and with your reduce() line mine: [[ 0.24112953-0.1020551j  -0.22988481+0.11903133j]
 [-0.22988481-0.11903133j  0.24112953+0.1020551j ]] . yours: [[ 0.29577303-0.1009189j  -0.24969598+0.08683577j]
 [-0.24969598-0.08683577j  0.29577303+0.1009189j ]]

Comment: `np.dot(T[0],np.dot(T[1], np.dot(T[2], np.dot(T[2],np.dot(T[3],T[4])))))` you have T[2] twice

Comment: I found the error. You are right. I was wrong. **One should NOT USE the np.dot() command as I did above!** I checked it with this code:  B = np.eye(2); B = [np.dot(B,T[i]) for i in range(0,5)], which gave the same result as your reduce() line

Comment: Err, I missed a lot of that conversation but glad you've got it sorted :)